# Creating an array of concrete instances of a generic class

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting

I have a generic class `Position<E>` and a concrete class `Card`. How do I create an array of type `Position<Card>`?

I tried:
`Position<Card>[] suitPositions = (Position<Card>[]) new Object[5];`
but I get a ClassCastException.

But when I try:
`Position<String>[] suitPositions = (Position<String>[]) new Object[5];`
it works just fine.

Comment: does `new Position<Card>[5]` not work?

Comment: No, that gives a Generic Array Creation error.

Comment: Use `(Position<Card>[])new Position<?>[5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the raw type to create the array:

```
Position<String>[] suitPositions = new Position[5];
```